# Problems getting openmpi-2.0.2 to work. ( MacOS Sierra )

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, openmpi

Have tried install openmpi-2.0.2 on my mac running on OSX Sierra 10.12.3 with similar results each time. 
Installing using the below :

> $ cd  openmpi-2.0.2
>
> $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
>
> $ make all
>
> $ sudo make install

After install wanted to test using :

> $ mpirun -n 4 hostname

&

> $ mpiexec -n 4 hostname

both resulting in :

> ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file orted/pmix/pmix_server.c at line
>   262 ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file ess_hnp_module.c at line 666
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process
>   is likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process
>   can fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
>   environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
>   here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
>   Open MPI developer):
>
> pmix server init failed   --> Returned value Bad parameter (-5)
>   instead of ORTE_SUCCESS

Any ideas on why this error occurs, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the question 8 here: https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=osx

> 8. I am using Open MPI 2.0.x and getting an error at application startup. How do I work around this?
>      On some versions of Mac OS X / MacOS Sierra, the default temporary directory location is sufficiently long that it is easy for an application to create file names for temporary files which exceed the maximum allowed file name length. With Open MPI, this can lead to errors like the following at application startup:
>
> shell$ mpirun ... my_mpi_app
>
> [[53415,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file ../../orte/orted/pmix/pmix_server.c at line 264
>
> [[53415,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file ../../../../../orte/mca/ess/hnp/ess_hnp_module.c at line
>
> The workaround for the Open MPI 2.0.x release series is to set the TMPDIR environment variable to /tmp or other short directory name.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please not that link only answers do not fulfill the standards of So. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks RT, ended up installing MPI 2.0.1 which works fine. When updating I will try your suggested workaround.