# MPI failed for some reason on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, installation, mpi

I installed MPI on macOS Mojave following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42780322/3566569) tutorial on Stack Overflow. I installed openmpi-2.0.4.tar.gz.

But when I tried to run that hello world program I get error:

```
[My-MacBook-Pro.local:40731] [[30181,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file orted/pmix/pmix_server.c at line 262
[My-MacBook-Pro.local:40731] [[30181,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file ess_hnp_module.c at line 667
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  pmix server init failed
  --> Returned value Bad parameter (-5) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems getting openmpi-2.0.2 to work. ( MacOS Sierra )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374825/problems-getting-openmpi-2-0-2-to-work-macos-sierra)

Comment: As a side note, Open MPI `2.0.2` is no more supported. I suggest you use the latest `4.0.1` instead (or the latest releases in the `v3.0` and `v3.1` series)

Answer (score 3):

export TMPDIR=/tmp 
(or some other temp directory, where the directory name is not too long)

Comment: Can you explain why does it answer the question?